# Remove duplicate fields with different data

Tags: linux, shell-script, text-processing, scripting

Original file `FinalResults.txt` contains the following:

```
loginName:name1
memoryInfo:jsHeapSizeLimit:2181038082
session:cabSessionID:
sessionStartTime:

loginName:name1
memoryInfo:jsHeapSizeLimit:2181038080
session:cabSessionID:
sessionStartTime:

loginName:name2
memoryInfo:jsHeapSizeLimit:2181038080
session:cabSessionID:
sessionStartTime:

loginName:name3
memoryInfo:jsHeapSizeLimit:2181038084
session:cabSessionID:
sessionStartTime:

loginName:name4
memoryInfo:jsHeapSizeLimit:2181038080
session:cabSessionID:
sessionStartTime:

memoryInfo:jsHeapSizeLimit:2181038080
session:cabSessionID:
sessionStartTime:

loginName:name5
memoryInfo:jsHeapSizeLimit:2181038080
session:cabSessionID:
sessionStartTime:

loginName:name1
memoryInfo:jsHeapSizeLimit:2181038082
session:cabSessionID:
sessionStartTime:

loginName:name6
memoryInfo:jsHeapSizeLimit:2181038083
session:cabSessionID:
sessionStartTime:
```

This is repeated multiple times throughout the original output. I would like to search through this file and create another output text file that should have 1 line per user and look like the following:

```
loginName:  memoryInfo:jsHeapSizeLimit:
```

The loginName and memoryInfo should be separated by a Tab space.

I want to exclude some names from this list.

This is what I have so far:

```
$ grep -e "^loginName\|^memoryInfo" FinalResults.txt | egrep -v 'name1|name2' | awk '$1!=p; {p=$1}' | paste -d"\t" - - > Test.txt
```

After removing the names, I am left with `memoryInfo` followed by `memoryInfo`.

How can I modify my script to have the output from this:

```
loginName:A memoryInfo:jsHeapSizeLimit: 1Gb
loginName:B memoryInfo:jsHeapSizeLimit: 2Gb
memoryInfo:jsHeapSizeLimit: 3Gb loginName:C
memoryInfo:jsHeapSizeLimit: 4Gb
```

[image]
To this:

```
loginName:A memoryInfo:jsHeapSizeLimit: 1Gb
loginName:B memoryInfo:jsHeapSizeLimit: 2Gb
loginName:C memoryInfo:jsHeapSizeLimit: 4Gb
```

Basically, it should be `Name, memoryInfo` in that pattern. If it is a `memoryInfo` followed by `memoryInfo`, I want the second one to be removed.

Comment: How to you get your `A`, `B`, `C` and `1Gb`, `2Gb`, `3Gb` from your input file?

Comment: That is already pre-generated on the `FinalResults.txt`

Comment: Please show a snippet of a real input file with a few `loginName:` and `memoryInfo:` lines that produces the wrong output with your script.

Comment: If I take your sample code and your sample input file I get `loginName:      memoryInfo:jsHeapSizeLimit`. This doesn't match what you say it produces.

Comment: I have added the picture. The main file `FinalResults.txt` has some entries without the loginName field which throws everything off. I posted a picture of the output on my original post so you see what I am talking about.

Comment: Add the input and output data as text, formatted as a code block. This allows us to copy/paste the data.

Comment: Also, I have `egrep -v 'name1|name2'`, which removes these `loginName` for the said users but not the associated `memoryInfo`. Therefore I have multiple back to back `memoryInfo`. If there is a `memoryInfo` followed by another `memoryInfo`, I would like them to be removed until the next field would be `loginName`, even if the `memoryInfo` has different data.

Comment: I added the `FinalResults.txt` information on my original post so you can copy and paste it now. You can run my code to see exactly the issue I run into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AWK for this task.

**First solution** using a similar `egrep` command to exclude users:

```
 egrep -v 'loginName:(name1|name2)' FinalResults.txt | awk '/^loginName:/ { login=$0; } # save line
     /^memoryInfo:jsHeapSizeLimit:/ { 
         if(login!="") { # only if we have a saved loginName line
             printf "%s\t%s\n", login, $0;
             login=""; # clear to avoid printing twice
         }
     }'
```

With the input from the question, the output is

```
loginName:name3 memoryInfo:jsHeapSizeLimit:2181038084
loginName:name4 memoryInfo:jsHeapSizeLimit:2181038080
loginName:name5 memoryInfo:jsHeapSizeLimit:2181038080
loginName:name6 memoryInfo:jsHeapSizeLimit:2181038083
```

**Second solution** with an extended AWK script and an exclude list in a separate file

Assuming you create a file `exclude` with all users to exclude, one per line

```
name1
name2
```

you can use an extended AWK script and supply the `exclude` file as the first file before the input data file(s)

```
awk 'NR==FNR {# condition is valid for first file only
        exclude[$0]=1; # add name to exclude map
        next; # stop processing, do not check other rules
     }
     /^loginName:/ { 
         name=substr($0,11); # extract name
         if (!( name in exclude )) login=$0; } # save line if not in exclude list
     /^memoryInfo:jsHeapSizeLimit:/ {
         if(login!="") { # only if we have a saved loginName line
             printf "%s\t%s\n", login, $0;
             login=""; # clear to avoid printing twice
         }
     }' exclude FinalResults.txt
```

This produces the same result as the first AWK script combined with `egrep`.

Comment: I added the `FinalResults.txt` information on my original post so you can copy and paste it now. You can run my code to see exactly the issue I run into.

Comment: This script does clean up to a certain extent, however any lines with `name1` and `name2` should be excluded along with the associated `memoryInfo`.

Comment: @IbrahimA Combined first AWK script with `egrep` command and added alternative solution

Comment: Much  appreciated! Works like a charm. Wish I had your skills!

Comment: @IbrahimA Working on UNIX or Linux and continuing to learn will surely improve your skills. I guess I started 20 years earlier than you.

Answer (score 1):

i Have done by below method

```
awk '/^loginName:/{x=NR+1}(NR<=x){print}' filename| sed "N;s/\n/ /g"| awk '$0 !~ /name[12]/{print $0}'
```

output

```
loginName:name3 memoryInfo:jsHeapSizeLimit:2181038084
loginName:name4 memoryInfo:jsHeapSizeLimit:2181038080
loginName:name5 memoryInfo:jsHeapSizeLimit:2181038080
loginName:name6 memoryInfo:jsHeapSizeLimit:2181038083
```

Comment: This works as well, now if I wanted to remove names like Elmo and Mickey, how would I go about modifying your script to reflect that?

Comment: I got it! Just replace `/name[12]/` with `/Elmo|Mickey/`

Comment: This is actually missing the tab in between `loginName` and `memoryInfo`