# How to add Tab Space in between awk / sed command in bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk, scripting

I have two separate lines being consolidated onto one line. The issue is that at the current moment, it is being separated by a space. I would like to know how I can separate the two lines into one line with a Tab spacing instead.

Here is the code I currently have:

`awk '/^loginName:/{x=NR+1}(NR<=x){print}'\t FinalResults.txt| sed "N;s/\n/ /g"`

I see the tab command is `%\t`, but where exactly would this go? Also, can you break down the current coding and explain in detail what everything does and what is the purpose as I am trying to learn how bash works.

Additional information: 
The question is related to this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/502156/330217.
The input file `FinalResults.txt` is the same as shown inthe other question.

Comment: Is this related to https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/502115/330217 ? Please show your input file `FinalResults.txt` and expected and actual output in the question.

Comment: It is, I gave you the best answer to that one. But this one was a shorter script so I was wondering how it worked and just focusing on the Tab command for this. I tried adding the %\t everywhere and no luck. I want it to show `Name` Tab `Memory` then next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `awk` script prints all lines starting with `loginName:` and the next line immediately following it regardless of its contents.

```
/^loginName:/{x=NR+1} # for matching lines store the record (line) number +1 into x
(NR<=x){print} # The condition will be true for the line matching the pattern above and the following line.
```

Read the documentation of `sed` and `awk`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/6255796/10622916 for `sed`'s `N` command.

Replace the `sed` command with

```
 sed "N;s/\n/\t/g"
```

to separate the lines with Tab instead of space.

Or change the `awk` script

```
awk '/^loginName:/{x=NR+1;l=$0}NR==x{print l "\t" $0}' FinalResults.txt
```

and omit the `sed` command.
If you want it even shorter

```
awk 'l{print l"\t"$0;l=0}/^loginName:/{l=$0}' FinalResults.txt
```

but a shorter script may be more difficult to understand.
(Here the condition for printing is the value of `l` being non-empty and not `0`, and `l` stores the `loginName:` line.)